# How to connect the database with Cordova generated mobile app?

Tags: android, html, cordova, web-applications, android-emulator

I have created a web app using HTML, CSS, Angular JS and bootstrap. I used Cordova to generate the mobile app but I am not able to access the database from the emulator (though I have access to it from the browser).
Could somebody please help?

I tried changing the address to (10.0.2.2), but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: why don't you use a rest api to fetch the data in json format and then display it in your app? why do you want to connect to the Database directly from the app? it's not a secure way